# (spfx) 'SPHttpClientConfiguration' is not assignable to to parameter of type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I've been fiddling around with this issue for some hours.

Here's my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-http": "^0.1.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.1",
    "@types/react": "0.14.46",
    "@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2"
}
```

Here's my import:

```
import {SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientConfiguration, SPHttpClientResponse,
ISPHttpClientConfiguration} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

Here's the function:

```
    private loadFieldsAPI(): Promise<object[]> {
    let clienturl: string = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + this.context.pageContext.list.id + "')/fields?$select=Id,Title'";


    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(clienturl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
            return response.json();
        });
    }
```

So far I've tried

- Removing my node_modules folder and doing `npm i`.
- Removing and reinstalling `@microsoft/sp-http` to several different versions
- Removing the sp-http reference from my package.json file.

The complete error is

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration'.`

Any suggestion as to what i can try next is very appreciated!

Comment: is this sharepoint online or 2016 on prem ?

Comment: This is sharepoint online

Comment: Refer this link - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/911

Comment: As per the link - I am still receiving the error after trying to remove the reference from package.json, and copying a new installation of the node_modules folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an older version of the @microsoft/sp-http package comparing to other @microsoft packages in your project. I'd suggest you create a new project and compare the list of dependencies with the list in your project.